# Are there any invented tonal languages in sci-fi and fantasy?

Tags: history-of, languages

Tone [is the use of pitch in language to distinguish lexical or grammatical meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tone_(linguistics)).

This does not mean that that tone is the exclusive conveyor of meaning, merely that it is relevant. For example, many people are aware that there are four different tonal variations of the syllable /ma/ in Mandarin, which all have different meanings. I.e. there exists minimal pairs of words, where the only distinguishing difference is the tonal pattern.

And note,

> Tonal languages are extremely common in Africa, East Asia, and Mexico, but rare elsewhere in Asia and in Europe; as many as seventy percent of world languages may be tonal.[<sup>1</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tone_(linguistics)#cite_note-FOOTNOTEYip20021.E2.80.933.2C_12.E2.80.9314-1)

Now, the languages we are familiar with in SF (e.g. Klingon, Dothraki, LOTR languages) obviously come from Western traditions, where lexical tone is lacking.

## Are there any invented languages in SFF that are tonal?

Clarifications:

- *Invented* means it must have been developed to some significant degree,  not just surmised.
- *Tonal* doesn't mean the meaning is conveyed **only** by tones; it means that tones, in combination with other variations in sound, are meaningful.

Comment: VTCers:   Please explain how exactly is it that you think that "Are there any invented tonal language in SF?"  qualifies for "This question does not appear to be about science fiction or fantasy" ?

Comment: They are VTC as a "recommendation/list" question... Personally,I do not see it as either... I voted to leave open in the queue.

Comment: I personally voted for "this is a list question" since the answer is either "yes" or "yes, and here is/are one/several examples" as seen thus far by the answers.

Comment: I voted to re open since I understand invented (in the context given by the examples of klingon, LOTR) as truly invented and not just hypothesized or just mentioned with few or no examples. In that sense there are not a lot of answers I can think of.

Comment: @Ram, that's a good point.   I couldn't put my finger on why many of the answers didn't feel like legitimate ones until you articulated it.   I'll clarify in the question.

Comment: To what degree do you consider it "developed"? Vocabulary? Syntax and grammar? Language shifts from evolution?

Comment: @Ram, the number of answers doesn't really affect how "listy" it is. As per our [policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2639/68872), if it requires knowledge of all works it's a list. as this one is.

Comment: I am concerned from some of the answers that perhaps the intent of the term "tonal language" is not being well conveyed (in that some answers seem to assume that a language consisting of musical notes is necessarily a *tonal language*, for example). You might consider including a short definition of what a tonal language is and perhaps a short explicit example (or perhaps an additional [link](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tone_language) to the one you already have) in order to head off more answers of that kind (unless you also seek those, of course).

Comment: One significant problem here is that you're restricting it to "sci-fi".  Neither "A Song of Fire and Ice" nor "Lord of the Rings" are sci-fi - they're as solidly fantasy as it's possible to get.  In the case of LotR, it is the inspiration for much of what we'd consider "fantasy" today.  Strongly suggest editting the question (and title) to include fantasy.

Comment: @Edlothiad "finite and well-scoped list questions are allowed here" that's in the policy link, if all available elements can be reasonably included in a canonical answer then its acceptable.

Comment: I still think that we need an understanding of what ThePopMachine considers to be "developed to some significant degree". I'm assuming it just means "the language wasn't just mentioned to be tonal, but actually appears in the work" and has a defined vocabulary and grammar.

Comment: Does "I am Groot!" qualify? Not sure if it is to be considered tonal or a language, but how it is said in each instance it conveys an awful lot of meaning. (Not sure if it counts as sci-fi (as opposed to comics) as well).

Comment: Good comments, especially @Glen_b. I will update a little more

Comment: @FuzzyBoots, respectfully, I didn't respond the first time you made the comment because I think it's a situation of "you'll know it when you see it".  If a language appears in a book merely by description, that is not developed.   If it appears will only a few words and no grammar or vocabulary, it's not developed.    From a practical point of view, I don't think there's going to be an example of a middle ground anyhow.    At the very least someone should be able to express some reasonable amount new ideas without just pulling new grammar and vocabulary out of thin air.

Comment: In addition to @bent 's answer of "I am Groot", the language spoken by [Mother Box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mother_Box) is completely tonal.  (It consists only of the word "ping", but the tones that it says the pings convey complete sentences.)  Since the entire language is just one word, that may not pass the "invented" test, so I'm just putting this as a comment.

Comment: In addition to "I am Groot", there is also the wookie language from Star wars, but that is all just surmised, so it doesn't qualify as an answer.

Comment: Voting to reopen, because per the [list question policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2639/36526), this question is "seeking something odd, rare, or not-obviously-stated in those works."

Comment: @Kevin - Did you read further down about these questions attracting a constant dribble of "me too" answers?

Comment: @Valorum: Seeing as that is the *last sentence* of the list questions policy, yes, I did.

Comment: @Kevin - And did you notice the constant dribble of "me too" answers below? ↓↓↓

Comment: @Valorum: Yes, I did see that this question has a higher-than-average number of answers, as I was scrolling past them in order to post my answer.

Comment: @Kevin - A whole bunch of single-example answers below a list question is what you'd expect to see.

Comment: @Valorum: Answers don't make questions off-topic.  Suggest taking it to meta?

Comment: @Kevin - I'm pointing out that list questions attract lists. Since this question is currently (and in my opinion rightly) closed, I don't see that it needs a meta question about it

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### [Láadan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A1adan)

Is a tonal constructed language created by Suzette Haden Elgin in 1982 included in her science fiction [Native Tongue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Tongue_(Suzette_Haden_Elgin_novel)) series. Actually a feminist science-fiction.

It was created with the explicit hypothesis that tonal language, unlike traditional western languages, are better suited to express women points of view.

The language was actually constructed and not just hypothetized, like other fictional languages, there are cassettes, a dictionary and grammar rules.

Comment: Sounds super interesting, would you recommend the series?

Comment: Y ahora que veo tu perfil, se conseguirá por acá? :P

Comment: @MauricioPasquierJuan it's on amazon I don't know about Argentina there are lots of bookshops and a feminist community I guess it can be found, I didn't read the book it came to my knowledge from a philosopher friend who likes fictional languages.

Comment: Your profile says you are in Argentina, sorry I just assumed. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @MauricioPasquierJuan I am in Argentina

Answer (score 16):

Close Encounters of the Third Kind

[You Tube link to Tones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m2JL0xABlrQ)

> Start with the tone. (Pinkish-red) - G Up a full tone. (Orange) - A
>   Down a major third. (Purple) - F  Now drop an octave. (Yellow) - F (an
>   octave lower) Up a perfect fifth. (White) - C

In the movie, the computer eventually takes over as it learns the tonal language.

[image]

> Musician: What are we saying to each other?
>
> Tech#1: It seems they're trying to teach us a **basic tonal vocabulary**.
>
> Tech#2: It's the first day at school, fellas.

Comment: Those tones were used as a cipher, spelling words with tones as letters.   That's not really a tonal language.  Burmese is a tonal language, where the tone of a word carries much of its meaning and the same word in different tones has multiple meanings -- but tones aren't treated as writing, at least not in human tonal languages.

Comment: @Zeiss - no - you're wrong. It was menat to be a mathematical language expressed tonally. Where in the movie does it say it's a cipher?

Comment: Hah!  But, I don't think the two uses of the word ‘tone’ actually intersect here.

Comment: @ZeissIkon - you might be getting confused when the scientists are using sign interpration of musical notes early in the film - they're literal using signs for "this note is an A" and are different to the signs used for actual roman letters

Comment: If this counts, then the way R2D2 "speaks" would count as well....

Answer (score 13):

As far back as 1827 with [Solresol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solresol), invented by François Sudre.

> Solresol words are made from one to five syllables or notes. Each of these may be one of only seven basic phonemes, which may in turn be accented or lengthened. There is another phoneme, silence, which is used to separate words: words cannot be run together as they are in English.
>
> The phonemes can be represented in a number of different ways – as the seven musical notes in an octave, as spoken syllables (based on solfège, a way of identifying musical notes), with the seven colors of the rainbow, symbols, hand gestures etc. Thus, theoretically Solresol communication can be done through speaking, singing, flags of different color – even painting.

While the actual language was not used, a very similar one appeared in *[Voyage to Faremido](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyage_to_Faremido)* in 1916.

> The term "Faremido" has a clear explanation: the inhabitants of Faremido use a language consisting purely of musical sounds (thus, their language is harmonic in the most literal sense). Every word is transcribed in the novel using syllables of solfege: sequences of the syllables Do, Re, Mi, Fa, So, La, Si. For example: "solasi", "Midore", "Faremido" etc. (Such a language has indeed been devised earlier: See Solresol.) In fact, all terms should be intoned instead of pronounced. Thus, in this world a musical language is used. The protagonist remarks that their speech is both wise (in the meaning) and beautiful (as music), thus thought and feeling are blurred to be the same for these beings.

Answer (score 9):

Jack Vance's "[The Moon Moth](http://www.unexploredworlds.com/RealPulp/htm/rpulp145.htm)" postulates a language (Sirenian) which not only requires that it be sung, but that specific musical instruments be used to accompany the speaker/singer to denote social and emotional meaning.

Answer (score 9):

In Raymond Feist's [Magician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magician_(Feist_novel)), the Tsurani have a tonal language.  A major part of the book involves the lead character (Pug) being captured as a slave.  When he and a fellow slave, Laurie, are asked how they learnt to speak the language so well, Laurie explains that he is a bard and has encountered similar tonal languages in his travels.  He specifically says that the meaning of words changes with their pitch.

Answer (score 6):

*T.H.E.M.*, by G.C. Edmondson, was the answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71634/story-identification-large-scale-space-combat-story).  One of the details of that story was that the enemy communication was transmitted over radio as just two tones, high and low, and the narrator character (who had a linquistic talent) learned it by just hearing it in the background over a longer period of combat.  The language itself was never reproduced in the novel, but it surely was tonal -- in fact, the full meaning was transmitted by the tones alone, without any morphemes required.

Comment: That's sorta like Morse code?

Comment: @Malandy And also how binary used to be stored on tapes and transmitted over copper telephone cables. Think "screeching" modems!

Comment: @CJDennis - Binary languages like this would be a language that basically no organic, evolved sapient would use, unless they needed to... It's not information dense enough for common use? ... Also, would it be called invented? It's basically Morse in another medium?

Comment: @Malandy I didn't invent it or try to use it -- I just read the novel when it was fairly fresh and remembered that little tidbit -- like I remember the name of the ship the protagonist/narrator was on, the *Nishrub*, Arabic for "water boy".

Comment: No... I'm wondering if this answer actually answers the question, 'cause it's asking for an "invented" language, which I think this fails...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how this might fit the bill.

In the Elder Scrolls series of games, dragons have a language of their own, [Dovahzul](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Language). This language is special because the tonality in its usage does not change the meaning of the sounds being spoken. It does, however, change the world around you.

One example: the word for fire in general is *yol*. Speaking it in a calm, neutral tone (i.e.: "*yol* is the word for fire, and also a greeting") will not have any effects, but "shouting" it will cause a stream of fire to come out from the mouth of the speaker, even if they are not a dragon (i.e.: a human).

I used a pair of quotes around "shouting" because the technical, in lore term for the activation of those words is "shout", but depending on the words, other changes in tone will trigger an effect. Whispering *zul*, *mey* or *gut* (*voice*, *fool* and *far*, respectively) is considered a "shout", and doing so will cause the voice of the speaker to be heard saying something else, somewhere else.

Dragons, the native speakers, don't seem too talkative. It is said that what is an argument to them seems like a fantastic, spectacular fight to non-dragon observers. As for the humans who study the language, they make vows of silence. They speak very little and in very considered sentences, because even a short phrase can cause a building to shake. I believe unintended swearing could affect the weather or kill those around them.

Answer (score 1):

The *Feline Wizards* series by Diane Duane makes liberal use of an invented tonal language called Ailurin.  It is described as the language of cats, and is said to have 37 distinct vowel sounds in addition to being "pitched" or tonal (the author also explicitly compares it to Mandarin Chinese and calls it "more sung than spoken").  The opening pages of *The Book of Night with Moon* claim that (most) humans are incapable of pronouncing it satisfactorily due to these complexities.  They also discuss some cultural differences between cats and humans which pop up repeatedly in the actual narrative (and were not just thrown in for "color").

The extent of development of Ailurin is unclear.  Vocabulary words are sprinkled throughout the books, largely untranslated, but their etymology and grammatical structure is never discussed in any significant detail.  It is also claimed that body language makes up a substantial proportion of feline communication, perhaps more than the spoken language itself.  I would see it as right on the edge of a "true" constructed language: the author has clearly invested a nonzero amount of effort into developing it, including a lot of careful thought about the psychology of the beings using it, but you can't freely compose new sentences based on currently available information.  So it's not quite at the same level as Klingon (say), but it's a lot more developed than the aliens from "Darmok" (for example), who have the opposite problem of too much grammar and not enough vocabulary (also, their grammar is a one-trick pony).